# SymPy: how to implement a general substitution for several "look-alike" terms?

Tags: python, lambda, sympy, substitution, symbolic-math

I have searched a lot through the questions and, honestly, couldn't find something that applies to my case.

I am working with the SymPy library in order to perform large calculations and it has been working tremendously well. However, my recent results have became too convoluted. So, I began to implement more definitions and symbols in order to perform several substitutions and narrow down the expression to a more feasible form. I have been able to do this, 'manually', for a lot of terms, which are too much particular to allow any kind of automation. But, there is a specific family of contributions in my expression that could be greatly simplified if I could run this simple substitution rule.

Let A be my complete expression. In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnNWt.png), the dots represent already simplified terms and the summation represents the general setup behind my query. My goal is to rewrite it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSVcb.png).

The T_k are just denoting generic terms; in fact, they are composed by several literal `Symbols`. In my code, the rho letter is associated to a single variable, `Symbol`-type. So, with that said, my problem could be exemplified as follows:

```
# sympy symbols: rho, a, b, c, d
# sympy functions: f, g, h
A = (a * b) * f(rho) + (c * d) * g(rho) + (a * c * d * b) * h(rho)

# apply some clever substitution method ???
A.subs(???)
  >>> f(a * b) * rho + g(c * d) * rho + h(a * c * d * b) * rho
```

Of course, in the above example, I could do it "by hand". The problem lies when there is a lot of terms like that. I tried to achieve my goal using `lambda` expressions, but couldn't make it work. The idea was: for any generic `lambda t`, I could try to input the map `{t * f(rho) : f(t) * rho}`, for each symbolic function (`# f, g, h`), but not caring about the particular companion terms.

I tried defining, for instance, `genSub_f = lambda t: A.subs(t * f(rho), f(t) * rho)`. However, in order to make the substitution, I would have to call `genSub_f(a * b)`, which works, but it's not practicable, since one would have to detain prior knowledge about the combinations of symbols that are going along with `f(rho)`. How to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Wild` symbols for this however there are a few ways to obtain your desired output.

One complication is it seems you don't want to apply the substitution
`f(a*b)*rho -> f(a*b*rho)`. There are a few ways to achieve this, however first I'll give an answer that does result in this substitution:

```
from sympy import *
rho, a, b, c, d = symbols("rho, a, b, c, d")
f, g, h = symbols("f, g, h", cls=Function)
A = (a * b) * f(rho) + (c * d) * g(rho) + (a * c * d * b) * h(rho)

w1, w2 = symbols("w1, w2", cls=Wild)

for ff in [f, g, h]:
    A = A.replace(w1*ff(w2), w2*ff(w1))

print(A)  # f(a*b*rho) + g(c*d*rho) + h(a*b*c*d*rho)
```

So what about excluding the substitution `rho*f(a*b) -> f(a*b*rho)`?

One approach is to exclude `rho` from the `Wild` matches by defining your `Wild` symbol `w1` like so (we also have to exclude the substitution `1*f(...) -> ...*f(1)`). This results in your desired output:

```
A = (a * b) * f(rho) + (c * d) * g(rho) + (a * c * d * b) * h(rho)

w1 = Wild("w1", exclude=[rho, 1])  # exclude unwanted substitutions
w2 = Wild("w2")

for ff in [f, g, h]:
    A = A.replace(w1*ff(w2), w2*ff(w1))

print(A)  # rho*f(a*b) + rho*g(c*d) + rho*h(a*b*c*d)
```

However, another way to achieve your desired output is to use `match` instead of `replace`. This way you won't have to explicitly exclude `rho` (with this approach the replacement is done manually so there's no need to worry about avoiding 'double' application of the replacement rules):

```
A = (a * b) * f(rho) + (c * d) * g(rho) + (a * c * d * b) * h(rho)

w1, w2, w3 = symbols("w1, w2, w3", cls=Wild)

for ff in [f, g, h]:
    m = A.match(w1*ff(w2) + w3)
    if m:
        A = m[w2]*ff(m[w1]) + m[w3]  # manual replacement

print(A)  # rho*f(a*b) + rho*g(c*d) + rho*h(a*b*c*d)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Ehren. That was really insightful. I wasn't aware of the existence of these `Wild` symbols. (I need to look up the documentation a little bit better. haha)